# Is it okay to rename "test" website folder to "public_html"

Tags: linux, ftp, cpanel

In CPanel I created a subdomain which is `test.mydomain.com` and I have my main domain which is `mydomain.com` both has `magento` websites. The old one which mydomain.com is stored in **public_html** and the `test.mydomain.com` is stored in **test** folder. both in same directory.

I copied them to my local PC. Also they are very very large sites with 30.000 products.

I would like to make test environment live. is it okay to change `public_html` to `public_html_old` and rename `test` folder to `public_html` in FTP client for example filezilla. This will help me not to move large files and folders across.

Answer (score 0):

This is safe to do it but before do this kind of process please stop apache and start after you change the folder name. It is more safe.

So i did change and it worked.